# How to compare words in array with words in tables

Tags: mysql, vb.net

How to compare words in array with words in tables in sql server
And get the words from the table

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far? Can you narrow down your question to something specific that can be answered?

Comment: SO isn't a code writing service. You will need to post some code showing what you have tried and possibly some examples of the inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: i tried read sentence in vb.net by textbox

Answer (score 1):

"And get the words from the table"  Have you established a connection to the database already?

I may be unclear in what you mean, but have you looked into

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter 

DataTable
```